# Trying to get position data from Aruco Package

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to get position data using the [aruco ros package](http://wiki.ros.org/aruco). I can get the marker to appear in the the screen, and it will be highlighted. But, no position data is being published to the markers topic. If I output to the screen in the launch file, there is output that identifies the marker, and has 4 2D points, as well as a 3D translation matrix, and a rotation transform(from what I read on the Aruco site). The last two are all 0. But the 2D points seem to be what I want. What topic should these be broadcasting on? And also I am assuming I'll need the transformation matrix and rotation transform, could they be defaulting to zero since I don't have a camera config file, because that is the case.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221337/trying-to-get-position-data-from-aruco-package/) by [JoshuaBRussell](https://answers.ros.org/users/25150/joshuabrussell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As it turned out the yaml configuration file was missing. Once I added(even a dummy one) it was able to broadcast it's position.

---

Originally posted by [JoshuaBRussell](https://answers.ros.org/users/25150/joshuabrussell/) with karma: 16 on 2016-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0